# How do I avoid the error: "Expected a literal value"?

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a scenario where the probability for a certain event to happen increases every time the event happened. I wanted to define a local variable for this but the error:

```
"Expected literal value" appeared (\*\*\*)
```

and now I don't know how to continue.

Code:

```
; If bird and cat share a patch, the cat should catch (kill) the bird with a certain probability (hunting-skill)

; This probablity shoud increase everytime the cat successfully catches a bird


to catch-event
  ask cats [
  let hunting-improvment [ hunting-skill * catch-rate-increase ]
    if any? birds-here [
      if random-float 1 <= hunting-skill [
        ask one-of birds-here [
          die 
          set hunting-skill hunting-skill + hunting-improvment
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `let` incorrectly with square brackets. Either use no brackets at all or if you want to use brackets, use round ones.

Here is a fixed minimum example of your code:

```
breed [cats cat]
breed [birds bird]

cats-own [hunting-skill catch-rate-increase]

to go 
  create-cats 5 [
    set hunting-skill 0
    set catch-rate-increase 1
  ]
end


to catch-event
  ask cats [
  let hunting-improvment (hunting-skill * catch-rate-increase)
    if any? birds-here [
      if random-float 1 <= hunting-skill [
        ask one-of birds-here [
          die 
          set hunting-skill hunting-skill + hunting-improvment
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```